# TypeScript Omit and keyof

Tags: typescript, generics

I encountered this type ModelFields and I am still trying to make sense of it.

```
 type ModelFields<T> = Partial<Omit<T, keyof BaseModel>> & {
      created_at?: Date;
      updated_at?: Date;
     };
```

I understand Partial, making all properties optional. I understand & (intersection of types).

Let start from keyof BaseModel which evaluates to:

```
"created_at" | "updated_at" | "modelName" | "primaryKey" | "columnIndexes" | "modelFields" | "indexes" | "findById
```

Typical usage is in findby where ModelFields is returned.

So in the construction of ModelFields type. A lot is done there. After picking properties of T, why are keys of BaseModel excluded? Can anyone break this down for someone trying to make sense of TypeScript to grasp the reason keyof BaseModel are excluded

```
 class BaseModel {
  created_at?: Date;
  updated_at?: Date;

  constructor() {}


  get modelName(): string {
    
  }

  
  get primaryKey(): FieldOptions | undefined {
   
  }

  get columnIndexes(): {[key: number]: Array<FieldOptions>;} {
    
  }

 
  get modelFields(): FieldOptions[] {
    
  }

  get indexes(): Index[] {
    
  }


  async findById(id: string | number): Promise<ModelFields<this> | undefined> {
    
  }

  
}
```

Another typical usage:

```
class AddressModel extends BaseModel {
 
  id!: number;

  address!: string;

}


class UserModel extends BaseModel {
 
  id!: number;
 
  nickName?: string;
  
  password?: string;

  defaultVal?: string;

  address?: ModelFields<AddressModel>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To provide a walkthrough with an example:

Suppose, T is a generic type and say, it is a type like the following

```
    interface ExampleT {
        created_at: Date;
        modelName: string;
        modelType: string;
    }
```

1. `Omit<T, keyof BaseModel>`. It will **remove** the **properties or keys** that are **present in** the **BaseModel**. So, in this case, it will remove `created_at`, `modelName` and the result will be something like `T1` below:

```
    interface T1 {
        modelType: string;
    }
```

2. `Partial<Omit<T, keyof BaseModel>>` or `Partial<T1>`. **Partial** makes all the keys present in the type to be **optional**. So it will become, like `T2`, below:

```
    interface T2 {
        modelType?: string;
    }
```

3. Next, we have the `&` (the intersection type). It will **combine** the two types. So

   `Partial<Omit<T, keyof BaseModel>> & { created_at?: Date; updated_at?: Date; }`

   or

   `T2 & { created_at?: Date; updated_at?: Date; }`

   or

   `ModelFields<ExampleT>`

   will become:

   ```
    interface T3 {
        modelType?: string;
        created_at?: Date; 
        updated_at?: Date;
    }
   ```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have this in your type definition

```
Partial<Omit<T, keyof BaseModel>>
```

This means

1. Take generic type T
2. **Remove properties of BaseModel** (because of [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk))
3. Make all properties of resulting type from above optional

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my confusion is, what will the properties of resulting type if T is of  type of BaseModel. See updated question.

Comment: It doesn't matter, only properties of BaseModel will be removed because you are omitting keyof BaseModel (and not for example keyof T). So only keys of BaseModel will be always removed

Comment: Whoa, Eureka, now I understand it. So for instance, ModelFields<AddressModel>, it will remove keys of BaseModel and retain keyof AddressModel which are id | address and add createdAt and updatedAt? So because AddressModel inherits those keys, they are being removed. Smart stuff. Is this correct?